# How to loop through specific keys in nested object?

Tags: javascript

I want to pull specific parts (definitely not all) from this object:

```
var metadata = {
    cat: {
        id: 'id',
        name: 'kitty',

    },    
    dog: {
        id: 'id',
        name: 'spot',
        owner: {
            name: 'ralph',
        }
    }    
    //tons of other stuff
};
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
var fields = ['cat.id', 'dog.name', 'dog.owner.name'];
fields.forEach( function(key) {
    console.log(metadata[key]); //obv doesn't work
});
```

This is a simplified scenario where I'm trying to validate specific fields in metadata. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the path to extract individual keys, then use a reducer to resolve the value, then map the results:

```
var path = function(obj, key) {
  return key
    .split('.')
    .reduce(function(acc, k){return acc[k]}, obj)
}

var result = fields.map(path.bind(null, metadata))
//^ ['id', 'spot', 'ralph']
```

Now you can log them out if you want:

```
result.forEach(console.log.bind(console))
```

Comment: sorry I can't seem to follow what the code is doing, would you mind explaining a bit? I've worked with the individual functions but can't seem to piece them together like you've done.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? What method in particular?

Comment: I don't understand the `path.bind` part. Is this how the flow goes? In `fields.map`, a field, say, `'cat.id'` gets passed to `path`, and `reduce` calls `metadata[cat]`, `metadata[cat][id]`, finally returns that value? Why is `path.bind(null)` necessary?

Comment: `map` expects a function; `bind` partially applies a function where `this` is the first argument which is not needed, thus `null`. You could write it with an extra anonymous function: `fields.map(function(x){return path(metadata, x)})`.